# WPF DataGrid: CanUserAddRows produces empty records (and of course empty rows)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

It isn't possible that only I have this problem.

I'm using a `DataGrid` with databinding. For simplicity I have only one column with strings. User should add new items.

Steps:

I/user clicks into last line to start editing. Now I/he press [ESC], all works fine (in event `CellEditEnding` I get the signal `EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel`)

so far, so good...

I/user clicks into last line again to start editing.

**Now** I/he clicks another row. The `DataGrid` don't cancel the current edit session and sends `EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit`.

The problem is, that I have now one empty record more in my collection (`DataGrid` added this at start editing). Okay, I thought, and tried to delete this item (in collection) programmatically if I detect an empty textbox in `CellEditEnding`. But this removes also the empty placeholder  line from DataGrid, too!?

How can I solve this behaviour?

Okay, here I added a minimal, but full sample project:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
<DataGrid Name="ctrlDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" CellEditEnding="OnCellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colName" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestApp
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>();
        for (char alpha = 'a'; alpha <= 'z'; alpha++)
            Items.Add(new Item() { Name = alpha.ToString() });

        ctrlDataGrid.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel || e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit && textBox != null && textBox.Text == "")
        {
            //Items.RemoveAt(Items.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: wheres your code?

Comment: Did you already try to [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcelleditendingeventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) the commit when there's no data?

Comment: EditAction is read-only :(
Cancel is to stay in editing mode

Answer (score 0):

You are close. As you probably found out, setting e.Cancel = true will cancel the event and leave you in edit mode. Instead, in your check for the empty text call the DataGrid's CancelEdit() method.

```
private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel)
    {
        // edit was cancelled
    } else if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit && textBox != null && textBox.Text == "")
    {
        // Can't commit empty string so cancel
        ctrlDataGrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have tryed, too, but doesn't work. But would be logical.

Comment: oops, my bad. didn't see the extended selection mode in your xaml. Add DataGridEditingUnit.Row to the CancelEdit call and see if that helps. (I've edited my answer)

Comment: **Great. This works!**
I did not notice that CancelEdit accepts an additional parameter. Why it is needed? What is the difference?
But the world could be so easy, if EditAction wouldn't be read-only :/

Comment: I think it is to allow for multiple edits in a single commit. When SelectionMode is Single you would only be able to edit a single cell at a time but Extended means there would be multiple cells selected. I am no expert in the DataGrid internals though.